node.js Javascript code to launch Chrome browser and load an extension
My goal is to write a Javascript that launches Chrome browser and loads an extension from a specified directory. I will need to run this Javascript file using Node.exe.
Commandline for chrome.exe: "chrome.exe --load-extension="Extensions_directory"
(Asking a basic question as I am not familiar with Javascript.)
I found this https://groups.google.com/g/runmyprocess/c/CapjstgMpGw that explains how to start a process using Javscript, but I wasn't sure of the right syntax.

Thank you for specifying your goal, please may you ask a question?
